# How to export a database from MS access 2007 to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, ms-access-2007

I have created a database with multiple tables in MS Access.
I want the same database to be transfered to MySQL.
What are the steps to do it??

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to install the [MySQL ODBC](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) driver, configure an ODBC connection to your target database in MySQL, then use Access' "Export" feature to copy the tables over. I have used this process in the past, and it has usually worked reasonably well.